# Magento 2 Custom Controller Action Created Using New Module Route Not Working

Tags: magento2, frontend, controllers, router

I am using magento2.3.5-p2 community edition ( open source )

I want to create a custom Controller so that I can post data using ajax to the Controller function created

client side will call the controller action like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('googletagmanager/gtm'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

the link to get the controller path will be `<?php echo $this->getUrl('googletagmanager/gtm'); ?>`

Thus to create this link `googletagmanager/gtm` I need to create a new module and put in the Controller class name `Gtm.php`

I have created a new module in
`app/code/GShop/GoogleTagManager`

I created a `routes.xml` file inside it in path `app/code/GShop/GoogleTagManager/etc/frontend/routes.xml` and the content as below

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="googletagmanager" frontName="googletagmanager">
            <module name="GShop_GoogleTagManager"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

I created a `module.xml` inside it at path `app/code/GShop/GoogleTagManager/etc/module.xml` and the content as below

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="GShop_GoogleTagManager" setup_version="1.1.0"/>
</config>
```

I created a `registration.php` at path `app/code/GShop/GoogleTagManager/registration.php` and content as below

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'GShop_GoogleTagManager',
    __DIR__
);
```

I created the controller at `app/code/GShop/GoogleTagManager/Controller/Gtm.php` with content as below

```
<?php
namespace GShop\GoogleTagManager\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Gtm extends Action
{
    protected $resultFactory;
    protected $customerSession;
    private $gtmLogger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \GShop\GoogleTagManager\Model\Logger $gtmLogger
    ) {
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->gtmLogger = $gtmLogger;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $data = [];

        /** User successful login */
        if ($this->customerSession->getGTMSuccessfulLogin()) {
            $data[] = $this->customerSession->getGTMSuccessfulLogin();
        }
        $this->customerSession->setGTMSuccessfulLogin(null);

        /** User unsuccessful login */
        if ($this->customerSession->getGTMUnsuccessfulLogin()) {
            $data[] = $this->customerSession->getGTMUnsuccessfulLogin();
        }
        $this->customerSession->setGTMUnsuccessfulLogin(null);

        /** Newsletter signup successful */
        if ($this->customerSession->getGTMSuccessfulNewsletterSignup()) {
            $data[] = $this->customerSession->getGTMSuccessfulNewsletterSignup();
        }
        $this->customerSession->setGTMSuccessfulNewsletterSignup(null);

        /** Newsletter signup unsuccessful */
        if ($this->customerSession->getGTMUnsuccessfulNewsletter()) {
            $data[] = $this->customerSession->getGTMUnsuccessfulNewsletter();
        }
        $this->customerSession->setGTMUnsuccessfulNewsletter(null);

        /** Product View */
        if ($this->customerSession->getGTMProductView()) {
            $data[] = $this->customerSession->getGTMProductView();
        }
        $this->customerSession->setGTMProductView(null);

        /** Wishlist Product Add */
        if ($this->customerSession->getGTMWishlistProductAdd()) {
            $data[] = $this->customerSession->getGTMWishlistProductAdd();
        }
        $this->customerSession->setGTMWishlistProductAdd(null);

        /** Wishlist Product Remove */
        if ($this->customerSession->getGTMWishlistProductRemove()) {
            $data[] = $this->customerSession->getGTMWishlistProductRemove();
        }
        $this->customerSession->setGTMWishlistProductRemove(null);

        /** Wishlist Product Update */
        if ($this->customerSession->getGTMWishlistProductUpdate()) {
            $data[] = $this->customerSession->getGTMWishlistProductUpdate();
        }
        $this->customerSession->setGTMWishlistProductUpdate(null);

        /** Wishlist Product Share */
        if ($this->customerSession->getGTMWishlistProductShare()) {
            $data[] = $this->customerSession->getGTMWishlistProductShare();
        }
        $this->customerSession->setGTMWishlistProductShare(null);

        /** User successful register */
        if ($this->customerSession->getGTMSuccessfulRegister()) {
            $data[] = $this->customerSession->getGTMSuccessfulRegister();
        }
        $this->customerSession->setGTMSuccessfulRegister(null);

        /** User unsuccessful register */
        if ($this->customerSession->getGTMUnsuccessfulRegister()) {
            $data[] = $this->customerSession->getGTMUnsuccessfulRegister();
        }
        $this->customerSession->setGTMUnsuccessfulRegister(null);

        // Get Item Deleted From Cart

        if ($this->customerSession->getGTMDeleteFromCart()) {
            $data[] = $this->customerSession->getGTMDeleteFromCart();
        }
        $this->customerSession->setGTMDeleteFromCart(null);

        // Get Event Of Wishlist Item Added To Cart

        if ($this->customerSession->getGTMWishListItemAddedToCart()) {
            $data[] = $this->customerSession->getGTMWishListItemAddedToCart();
        }
        $this->customerSession->setGTMWishListItemAddedToCart(null);

        // Get Event Of Wishlist All Item Added To Cart

        if ($this->customerSession->getGTMWishListAllItemAddedToCart()) {
            $data[] = $this->customerSession->getGTMWishListAllItemAddedToCart();
        }
        $this->customerSession->setGTMWishListAllItemAddedToCart(null);

        // Get Event Checkout Cart Quantity Added

        if ($this->customerSession->getGTMCheckoutAddToCart()) {
            $data[] = $this->customerSession->getGTMCheckoutAddToCart();
        }
        $this->customerSession->setGTMCheckoutAddToCart(null);

        // Get Event Checkout Cart Quantity Decreased

        if ($this->customerSession->getGTMCheckoutRemoveFromCart()) {
            $data[] = $this->customerSession->getGTMCheckoutRemoveFromCart();
        }
        $this->customerSession->setGTMCheckoutRemoveFromCart(null);

        // Clear Checkout Event If Checkout Stage Of GTM Not In Step 4

        $clear_checkout_session = true;

        if($this->customerSession->getGTMInCheckoutStage()){
            if($this->customerSession->getGTMInCheckoutStage() == 4){
                $clear_checkout_session = false;
                $data[] = $this->customerSession->getGTMProceedToCheckout();
                $this->customerSession->setGTMInCheckoutStage(null);
            }
        }
        
        if($clear_checkout_session){
            $this->customerSession->setGTMInCheckoutStage(null);
            $this->customerSession->setGTMProceedToCheckout(null);
        }

        // $this->gtmLogger->info($data);

        $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultJson->setData($data);

        return $resultJson;
    }
}
```

I had make sure to follow this step in making the route

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/routing.html

But I can't seem to figure out which part I miss that makes the URL cannot be accessed, it always throws out error 404

Can anyone please help me point out any places that I miss or guide me to understand why it is not working

Any help is kindly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should create action "index.php" in controller folder. So your folder structure should be like

app/code/GShop/GoogleTagManager/Controller/Gtm/Index.php file.

Comment: Yes, it works for me.

You need to create index.php and then work a new route.

Thanks

Comment: that's all right. please use same way

Answer (score 2):

You need to first create the controller and then the function(.php file). Like following:

> Vendor/Module/Controller/Controller_name/Function.php

[image]

Comment: Then in your url, put it like  route_name/controller_name/Function.php